# Saving output of a for-loop to file

Tags: python, file, loops, save

I have opened a file with blast results and printed out the hits in fasta format to the screen.

The code looks like this:

```
result_handle = open("/Users/jonbra/Desktop/my_blast.xml")

from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
blast_record = blast_records.next()
for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
        print '>', alignment.title
        print hsp.sbjct
```

This outputs a list of fasta files to the screen.
But how can I create a file and save the fasta output to this file?

Update: I guess I would have to replace the print statements within the loop with something.write(), but how will the '>', alignment.title we written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create a file object:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "w") # Use "a" instead of "w" to append to file
```

You can print to a file object:

```
print >> f, '>', alignment.title
print >> f, hsp.sbjct
```

Or you can write to it:

```
f.write('> %s\n' % (alignment.title,))
f.write('%s\n' % (hsp.sbjct,))
```

You can then close it to be nice:

```
f.close()
```

Comment: all operations after opening file should be wrapped with try ... finally to ensure that file will be correctly closed

Comment: In a long running process, yes, in a simple script it doesnt matter as files will be closed when script exits.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
with open("thefile.txt","w") as f
  for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
      f.write(">%s\n"%alignment.title)
      f.write(hsp.sbjct+"\n")
```

prefer not to use `print >>` as that won't work anymore in Python3

Answer (score 4):

you can use `with statement` to ensure that file will be closed

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open('/Users/jonbra/Desktop/my_blast.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
    blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
    blast_record = blast_records.next()
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            outfile.write('>%s\n%s\n' % (alignment.title, hsp.sbjct))
```

or use `try ... finally`

```
outfile = open('/Users/jonbra/Desktop/my_blast.xml', 'w')
try:
    from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
    blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
    blast_record = blast_records.next()
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            outfile.write('>%s\n%s\n' % (alignment.title, hsp.sbjct))
finally:
    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two general approaches. Outside of python:

```
python your_program.py >output_file.txt
```

Or, inside of Python:

```
out = open("output_file.txt", "w")
for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
        print >>out, '>', alignment.title
        print >>out, hsp.sbjct
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the code above posted by OP did not work for me.. I modified a bit

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
f = open('result.txt','w')
for record in NCBIXML.parse(open("file.xml")) :
    for alignment in record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            f.write(">%s\n"%alignment.title)
            f.write(hsp.sbjct+"\n")
```